# Failure of ambari at the phase of Install, Start and Test

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I hit following error when the installation of HDFS client is started :

```
raise Fail("Applying %s failed, parent directory %s doesn't exist" % (self.resource, dirname))
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Applying File['/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/hadoop-policy.xml'] failed, parent directory /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf doesn't exist
```

Comment: Did you try client installation multiple times ? If yes before retrying you should run "yum -y erase hdp-select" on client node manually and then start installation again.

Comment: thanks it was a problem of internet connection